# Insert data in only DataGridView in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, datagridview

I have a DataGridView in asp.net with C#. I want to insert data into only DataGridView with row by row. Finally, I want to Insert data into database from DataGridView. How can I do it?

Comment: How can it Possible that you have only accepted answers to 22% of the questions you've asked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nahid, I hate to sound unfriendly, but you are in the wrong place.  What you really need is a basic book on programming ASP.NET.  Every one of them has chapters devoted to this exact topic.  If you don't want to spend money, then visit your local library.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276229/best-book-on-asp-net-3-5-c-programming) is a good StackOverflow thread with book suggestions.